# Modular AJAX loading indicator with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, css

I am trying to show a loading image (and turn the parent transparent) for a page with many AJAX requests. What would be the most efficient way to add/remove the loading icon and opacity for each div independently?

Here is what I have so far. The problem with my approach is that the opacity is applied to the gif too, which is not what I want. Is there an easy fix to my code or a better approach to this?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/x4C2t/

HTML:

```
<div id="a" class="box">A</div>
<div id="b" class="box">B</div>
<div id="c" class="box">C</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.fn.loading = function(show){
    if(show){
        this.prepend('<div class="loading-centered"></div>');
        this.css({ opacity: 0.3 });
    }else{
        this.children('.loading-centered').remove();
        this.css({ opacity: 1 });
    }
};

$('#a').loading(true); //start  
setTimeout(function(){ $('#a').loading(false); }, 3000); // stop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would keep the styling in the CSS and just use JS to inject / remove the element http://jsfiddle.net/x4C2t/7/

```
$.fn.loading = function(show){
    if(show){
        this.prepend('<div class="loading-centered"></div>');
    }else{
        this.children('.loading-centered').remove();
    }
};
```

css:

```
.box {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    margin: 10px;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px;
    background: #eee;    
    position: relative;
}

.loading-centered {
    background:url('http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/24.gif') center center no-repeat white;
    position:absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius:10px;
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Nice! This is clever. Out of curiosity, could you explain why adding `position:relative;` to `.box` is needed?

Comment: postion relative is needed so the absolutely position element can be placed appropriately. If you remove you should see it break. Check out [this article](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning)

Answer (score 0):

Opacity applies to an elements children as well. Instead of using opacity just make the background of the parent have more opacity with rgba colors. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/x4C2t/6/) is an example. Also you were using

```
setInterval(function(){ $('#a').loading(false); }, 3000);
```

When you should have done

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#a').loading(false); }, 3000);
```

That was causing the page to crash for me.

Comment: I want the children to have opacity lowered as well to show that they are inactive until the AJAX is finished. Thanks for pointing out the `setTimeout`. I will update it in my example. Also note, you should always post your code in your answer in addition to your link on jsfiddle.